# How to scroll horizontally to an item in a container while keeping it centered?

Tags: javascript

I have a list of items in a container. The container takes the full width of the parent, allowing the items to overflow horizontally if needed. Here's what it looks like:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px dotted black;
}

li {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

a.active {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul id="container">
  <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="active" id="element">Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
</ul>
```

In the list of items, there is one that has the `.active` class. I want to horizontally scroll the container in a way such that this item is exactly centered. To do this, I wrote the following function:

```
function toMiddle(element, container) {
    if (container === undefined) {
        container = window;
    }
    var elementRect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    var absoluteElementLeft = elementRect.left;
    var middleDiff = (elementRect.width / 2);
    var scrollLeftOfElement = absoluteElementLeft + middleDiff;
    var scrollX = (scrollLeftOfElement - (container.getBoundingClientRect().width / 2));
    container.scrollTop = 0;
    container.scrollLeft = scrollX;
}
```

And I'm trying to call this to center the container as follows:

```
toMiddle(document.getElementById("element"), document.getElementById("container"));
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work properly. Any idea how I can fix this? And what exactly am I doing wrong here?

**Please note**, `scrollIntoView()` works perfectly well, but it scrolls the whole page vertically as well, which is not an acceptable thing for my use case.

Comment: I've tried to run your code, the active element seems centered as you expected. `scrollIntoView()` does not make that active element centered but you want it that way?
https://jsfiddle.net/ucdyhfws/

Comment: **I'm not exactly sure what you mean by:** ___"in a way such that this item is exactly centered".___  Are you saying you want the `.active` element to be dead-center when you have scrolled all the way out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.offsetLeft` method to find distance from left instead of `.getBoundingClientRect()` method. And count width of active item with `.clientWidth` method instead of `.width` and I also added `.resize` method for active item keeping it `centered`.

*Useful links:*
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetLeft
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientWidth

```js
function toMiddle(container_id) {
    var container = document.getElementById(container_id);
    var elementRect = document.querySelector('#' + container_id + ' .active');
    var absoluteElementLeft = elementRect.offsetLeft;
    var middleDiff = (elementRect.clientWidth / 2);
    var scrollLeftOfElement = absoluteElementLeft + middleDiff;
    var scrollX = (scrollLeftOfElement - (container.clientWidth / 2));
    container.scrollTop = 0;
    container.scrollLeft = scrollX;
}
/*Initialize on page load*/ 
toMiddle("container");


/*Window resize then active item tab should be centered*/ 
var timeout = 0;
window.onresize = () => {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        toMiddle("container");
    }, 500)
}

/*Click on item tab then should be centered*/ 
var allItem = [...document.querySelectorAll('#container li a')]
allItem.forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener('click', (e)=> {
        allItem.forEach(ele => {
            ele.classList.remove('active');
        })
        /*Add active class*/ 
        e.target.classList.add('active');

        /*Call the function for set item tab in centered*/ 
        toMiddle("container");
    })
});
```

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px dotted black;
    position: relative;
}
li {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 4px 8px;
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    transition: 0.5s ease-in;
}
a.active {
    background-color: #0156e8;
    border: 1px solid #00389a;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<ul id="container">
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 7</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 8</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 9</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 10</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 11</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 12</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 13</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 14</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 15</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 16</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 17</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="active">Item 18</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 19</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 20</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 21</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 22</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 23</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 24</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 25</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 26</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 27</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 28</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 29</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 30</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 31</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 32</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 33</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I don't see how this is centering anything. It looks the same as the OP's example.

Comment: Run my snippet to click on *Run code snippet* button so you will see Item 18 tab in centered. And then click *Full page* so you will also realize Item 18 will auto set in centered or you can also check with window resize to active `Item 18` will auto adjust in centered. And also click Item * then that clicked Item tab will set in centered.

Comment: This works nicely, I think I was missing the `position: relative` on the `<ul>` which you added. Thank you so much!